# Why does a class have a "constructor" field in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

A class is supposed to have a `prototype` field that supplies default fields. For example, `prototype.constructor` defaults to the constructor function (i.e., the class itself) and is therefore accessible as the `constructor` field in new *objects*:

```
function MyClass(){}
console.log(MyClass.prototype.constructor === MyClass); // true
console.log(new MyClass().constructor === MyClass); // true
```

That's all fine and good. However, if we accidently confuse the class and the object, we would expect an error, since the class shouldn't have a `constructor` field. But it does:

```
console.log("constructor" in MyClass);        // true
console.log(MyClass.constructor === MyClass); // false
```

Why does the class itself have a constructor field, and why is it not the same as `protoype.constructor`? Wouldn't this lead to lots of bugs, since a program could inadvertently access the `constructor` field of a *class*?

Comment: `MyClass` it itself an object: It's a `Function` object. `MyClass.constructor` is therefore the Function constructor! `console.log(MyClass.constructor == Function.prototype.constructor) /* true */`

Comment: using in operator you check not only the object but also their prototype...

Comment: I'm confused about your confusion. A class has a constructor. Once constructed, the object "is a" class instance and therefore has a constructor too. If you want to construct another object from the object reference, you can just do `var newInstance = new myObject.constructor();`. Obviously you could use `Object.create` too, but whateverr. Not sure there's much risk of programs "accidentally" accessing a `constructor` property any more than "accidentally" accessing its `__proto__` property...

Comment: @Heretic The question is why does a class have a constructor. The class wasn't constructed by a function. It was constructed by a *function definition statement*.

Comment: @Raymond Thank you for explaining. Indeed, the constructor of `MyClass` seems to be a built-in function that can construct any function. For example: `MyClass.constructor("console.log('hello');")();` prints `hello`.

Comment: For any object, `object.constructor` is the constructor for creating another instance of that object. Classes are objects too. They are Function objects. So `MyClass.constructor` is the constructor for creating another Function object. `MyClass.constructor("blah")` is just a confusing way of writing `new Function("blah")`.

Comment: @Raymond. Thank you for explaining the general rule. OK. I hadn't realized that a function definition statement would (at least conceptually) be calling a generic function constructor. I would accept an answer that combines your explanations and maybe an example of how the Function constructor works.