# Can we change the type of object by change constructor attr in java script?

Tags: javascript

It is said that in java script the interpretor use the constructor attribute to determain type of object.

For example:

```
function Person(name){this.name=name}

var person = new Person('jack')
```

In this case the person.constructor will be function Person

So I think if I change the person.constructor = some other constructor function

The java script interpretor will recognize person as another type.

Here is my test

```
function Car(brand){this.brand=brand}

person.constructor = Car

person.__proto__.constructor = Car

person instanceof Car 
return false
```

Why interpretor still recognize person as type of Person nor Car?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6529410/5156549) - 
**You can't change the constructors of an object, you can however change the 'type' of the object the constructor returns.**

Comment: `X instanceof Y` is the same as `X.__proto__ == Y.prototype`. `constructor` is only informational, changing it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use the `__proto__` property of objects: although standardised in EcmaScript2015, it is also deprecated in favour of [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf). Both work however if you change the prototype, not the constructor:

```js
function Person(name){this.name=name}

var person = new Person('jack')

function Car(brand){this.brand=brand}

Object.setPrototypeOf(person, Car.prototype);
// This also works:
// person.__proto__ = Car.prototype;

console.log(person instanceof Car); // true
```

So it is not the constructor property that defines the prototype chain, but the `__proto__` property.

Comment: Could you please let me know whether this answered your question?